# ubuntu 13.04 not booting with Gigabyte GT440

Tags: boot, ati

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 in my PC. I had Ubuntu 11.10 & Win7 before (that works together correctly).

I begin install after erasing all Linux partitions (with Ubuntu installer). 
after install and reboot, Ubuntu is not booting up now!

I have Gigabyte GT440 VGA and my main board is Asus m4a78t-mle that have onboard ATI VGA.
When I don't use GT440 VGA (unplug the Card), Ubuntu 13.04 can boot with on board VGA, but with GT440 not boot, and presents a black screen with a lot of reports of Linux booting. thus hanging. what I should do now?

Comment: Did you tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely booting, it is just getting stuck.

Look into the nomodeset option by following the guide here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132